# How to check disk usage of directories in a particular partition?

Tags: command-line-interface, disk-space-utilization, partition

If I use "df /dev/sda1 -h", it only shows the whole usage info like used and avail. But I want to see the usage of each directory. However, if I do "du -h --max-depth=1", it shows all the directories under "/" but some of them are not related to "/dev/sda1". Is there a way to combine the two, as titled? Thanks.

To clarify from the answers provided,

```
$ cd /
$ sudo du --max-depth=1 -x -h
3.6G    ./tmp
4.0K    ./private
310M    ./opt
4.0K    ./crl
3.4M    ./lib32
2.6G    ./usr
0   ./dev
8.0K    ./db
8.0K    ./mnt
11M ./root
0   ./sys
16K ./lost+found
4.0K    ./certs
8.7M    ./bin
0   ./run
4.0K    ./selinux
4.0K    ./srv
7.7M    ./etc
0   ./proc
385M    ./lib
718M    ./home
4.0K    ./ctel
4.0K    ./lib64
8.1M    ./sbin
1.2G    ./var
4.0K    ./boot
8.0K    ./media
```

Among them, "/ctel" and "/boot" are mounted on another partition, which I don't want to see.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`du --max-depth=1 -x` should do the trick. Option `-x` means not to follow other file-systems.

Answer (score 0):

from `du(1)` (man page):

```
  -P, --no-dereference
          don't follow any symbolic links (this is the default)
  -x, --one-file-system
          skip directories on different file systems
```